# Dynamic html table is not displayed correctly

Tags: php, html

Looking at my dynamic html table code,  it is currently displaying the table like this below:

[image: table not displayed correctly]

This is obviously incorrect and it should be display the table as below:

[image: what table should look like]

I am guessing there is something wrong with the mark up of the code but I can't seem to see where the problem lies. Does anybody know where the problem is in order to be able to get the correct table layout?
PHP:

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

}

$assessment = $_SESSION['id'];
    include('connect.php');

    $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, q.QuestionMarks 
    FROM Session s 
    INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
    JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId
    WHERE s.SessionName = ?
    ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer";

    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 


    // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionContent = array();
    $searchAnswer = array();
    $searchMarks = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array

    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbQuestionMarks);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent;
        $searchAnswer[] = $dbAnswer;
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
    }?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="Marks" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
            <th class='questionth'>Question</th>
            <th class='answerth'>Answer</th>
            <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
            <th class='noofmarksth'>Total Marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    $row_span = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
    $prev_ques = '';
    foreach($searchQuestionId as $key=>$questionId){?>
        <tbody>   
            <tr class="questiontd">
            <?php
            if($questionId != $prev_ques){?>
                <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$questionId?> <input type="hidden" name="q<?=$questionId?>_ans_org" class="q<?=$questionId?>_ans_org" value="<?=$searchMarks[$key]?>"><input type="hidden" name="q<?=$questionId?>_ans" class="q<?=$questionId?>_ans" value="<?=$searchMarks[$key]?>"></td>
                <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$searchQuestionContent[$key]?> </td>
            <?php
            }else{?>
                <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" ></td>
                <td class="questioncontenttd" ></td>
            <?php
            }?>
                <td class="answertd" name="answers[]"><?=$searchAnswer[$key]?></td>
                <td class="answermarkstd">
                <input class="individualMarks q<?=$questionId?>_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
                </td>
            <?php
            if($questionId != $prev_ques){?>
                <td class="noofmarkstd q<?=$questionId?>_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$searchMarks[$key]?></td>
            <?php
            }else{?>
                <td class="noofmarkstd"  q_group="1"></td>
            <?php
            }?>
            </tr>
        <?php
        $prev_ques = $questionId;
    }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Below is what the print_r of the arrays show:

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZLX6.png) => 1 [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY2ki.png) => 2 ) Array ( [0] => Name
>   three features in a ROM [1] => Name three features in a ROM [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZLX6.png) =>
>   Name three features in a ROM [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY2ki.png) => Here is a single answer ) Array (
>   [0] => A [1] => B [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZLX6.png) => D [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY2ki.png) => True ) Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 5 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZLX6.png)
>   => 5 [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY2ki.png) => 5 )

Comment: where are you checking the question id not equal to prev_quues twice

Comment: @MianKhurramIjaz Reason for that is because if you look at my table, Each question has only one question and one total marks but they can have either one or multiple answers. The reason why there is prev_ques twice is so that it adds likes a rowspan to columns Question and Total Marks if a question has multiple answers. This should in order to be able to get the layout wanted for the second screen shot

Comment: you need to post the print_r of the array as well very hard to tell where is the problem right now cannot run your code it would be wise to have the that tried on pastebin or codepad where other can run it.

Comment: @Milan I include the print_r for the arrays and its shown in the question at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have a rowspan for your title, I am not sure why you're adding

```
<td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" ></td>
<td class="questioncontenttd" ></td>
```

When the title is not new. I would simply remove this else statement as well as the above two lines.

Same for the second else statement and its html code. Remove it.

```
<tr class="questiontd">
<?php
if($questionId != $prev_ques){?>
     <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" ...></td>
     <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$searchQuestionContent[$key]?> </td>
 <?php }?>
 <td class="answertd" name="answers[]"><?=$searchAnswer[$key]?></td>
 <td class="answermarkstd">
 <input class="individualMarks q<?=$questionId?>_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
 </td>
 <?php
 if($questionId != $prev_ques){?>
     <td class="noofmarkstd q<?=$questionId?>_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="<?=$row_span[$questionId]?>"><?=$searchMarks[$key]?></td>
<?php }?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's just a wild guess..
what happens if you remove

```
else{?>
                <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" ></td>
                <td class="questioncontenttd" ></td>
            <?php
            }
```

and

```
else{?>
                <td class="noofmarkstd"  q_group="1"></td>
            <?php
            }
```

from your code..